# Get rid of CMake Rules folder

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Is there a way to get rid of the `CMake Rules` folders in targets in Visual Studio?

[image: solution explorer]

In this case the `game` target uses [cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) for precompiled header support and the `omg` target has a custom command that parses the `.mix` file and outputs the `..._gen.h` file.

Also would it be possible to remove the `CMakeLists.txt` file from there too? I know it's there for convenience but in my workflow it isn't that useful.

**EDIT:** Started a second bounty because I really need this - these "CMake Rules" folders are bloating my solution explorer because I have 100+ projects which all have them!

I would accept anything - a CMake way, a VS way (some "solution explorer view" or macro or whatever)...

**EDIT 2:**

here is sort-of the cmake for the `omg` target:

```
add_library(omg SHARED D:/omg.cpp D:/omg.mix)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT D:/omg_gen.h MAIN_DEPENDENCY D:/omg.mix COMMAND python D:/mixify.py D:/omg.mix D:/omg_gen.h)
add_custom_target(${target}_gen_${mix_name_only} DEPENDS ${gen_header})
add_dependencies(omg omg_gen)
target_sources(omg PUBLIC D:/omg_gen.h)
```

so `omg_gen.h` is generated from `omg.mix` and then included in `omg.cpp`

Comment: CMakeLists.txt is needed by CMake, the file contains all the stuff CMake will execute. Wanting them to be removed, is like asking wether you can get rid of all your C++ source files.

Comment: @usr1234567 ok - not removing the CMakeLists.txt makes sence. But how about the ```CMake Rules``` folder?

Comment: @usr1234567 I do use out-of-source builds. The problem is that my targets have custom commands attached and so these CMake_Rules folders pop up in the solution explorer. And I have hundreds of such targets (projects in the solution) and my solution explorer is bloated with stuff I don't want to see.

Comment: Can please clarify which CMake and Visual Studio versions you are using?

Comment: @Florian 2015 - but I can migrate to 2017 RC if needed - was planning on switching to 2017 when it gets released - I ride the wave of the latest tools

Comment: The interesting thing here is I was googling on how to add a Rules folder to my CMake + Visual Studio projects because I don't have one and there are dozens of .rules files in the root level getting in my way. Edit: It appears it was a single library in a project with 20 to 30 targets and upgrading CMake from 3.17.2 to 3.17.5 fixed this and an additial source_group issue although it's not listed in the release notes. Not sure I cleaned the build folder and regenerated multiple times without being able to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.rule` files are needed by CMake to attach the custom commands to some "dummy" self-generated file, if there are no input files given. You can see this when you look at the `.rule` file properties of your Visual Studio project in question (see `Custom Build Tool/General/Command Line`).

If you're not changing the CMake script code containing those target, you can't get rid of them.

You can only move them into the project's root source folder or any other folder you specify.

I've successfully tested the following example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(NoRulesSourceGroup NONE)

# Overwrite the rule for "CMake Rules" with do-not-match-anything (-> root)
source_group("CMake Rules" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "^$")

# Move ".rule" files somewhere else
source_group("Some Other Source Group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "\\.rule$")

add_custom_target(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Hello World"
)
```

---

**Edit**: You could also combine the above regular expression with a match for `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
source_group("Some Other Source Group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "CMakeLists\\.txt|\\.rule$")
```

---

**Edit**: If you can modify your CMake script code, you should add to your [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) call:

> ```
> MAIN_DEPENDENCY
> ```
>
> Specify the primary input source file to the command. This is treated just like any value given to the DEPENDS option but also suggests to Visual Studio generators where to hang the custom command. At most one custom command may specify a given source file as its main dependency.

In your case you won't even need the additional custom target since you have a dependency through the header file. I've successfully tested the following derived from your question's example:

```
file(WRITE omg.cpp "")
file(WRITE omg.mix "")

add_library(omg SHARED omg.cpp omg.mix)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/omg_gen.h 
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY omg.mix 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/omg.mix ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/omg_gen.h
)
target_sources(omg PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/omg_gen.h)
```

**References**

- [`source_group()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html)
- [Source/cmMakefile.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmMakefile.cxx#L92)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

I tried to put both the ```.rule``` files and the ```CMakeLists.txt``` file in the same ```"Some Other Source Group"``` folder but it didn't work - only the rules went into it.
When I tried to put the ```.rule``` files and the ```CMakeLists.txt``` in separate folders it worked.
Anyway...
What should I do to add an input to my custom commands so there are no ```.rule``` files to begin with? I've already used ```OUTPUT```/```DEPENDS```/```COMMAND```/```COMMENT``` - perhaps i need to use ```MAIN_DEPENDENCY```?

Comment: OMG! Using ```MAIN_DEPENDENCY``` as opposed to ```DEPENDS``` removed the ```.rule``` files! OMG thanks!

So there is no way to hide or remove the ```CMakeLists.txt``` files...

You get the bounty. But just as a side question - do you know a way to hide the ```References``` thingie that VS puts in each project? This is not CMake specific...

Comment: @onqtam You are welcome. If you could add some CMake code example containing e.g. the `omg` target, I could add a proposal from my side. And yes, I meant `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` to declare an input file where CMake can add the `COMMAND`s to. And could you add what you have tried to put `CMakeLists.txt` into a source group? Did you try to use absolute paths or a regex in the `source_group()` call in question?

Comment: I edited my question with *sample* (not the actual - I use lots of macros) cmake code for the omg target. Not sure what there is to propose to CMake... Not sure if this is a common "problem" - if you see a possible usage pattern beyond my case...

For the ```CMakeLists.txt``` I tried this: ```source_group("Some Other Source Group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "CMakeLists.txt")``` after the same line but for ```.rule``` (as you gave it) - but when both were present - only the ```.rule``` files ended in that filter - and when only the cmakelists line was present - it went in the filter properly...

Comment: @onqtam Updated my answer accordingly. And sorry, but I don't know how to hide the project's `References`.

Comment: Thanks! Just got rid of 100+ unnecessary targets :D I had them grouped in a folder so it wasn't a problem but still unnecessary :)